# How to get layout of this component to other component in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a sample file:

```
/components/com_test/views/test/tmpl/abc.php
```

And

```
/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
```

In `default.php of com_content` i using code call layout of com_test

```
...
<?php 
require('index.php?option=com_test&view=test&tmpl=component&layout=abc'); 
?> 
...
```

But result not show layout abc in com_content, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't dealt with directly in v2.5, but the below code works in Joomla's earlier MVC :

**`view.html.php`**

```
class myComponentViewmyModel extends JView
{
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
    global $mainframe;
    if($this->getLayout() == 'abc') {
        $this->_displayAbc($tpl);
        return;
    }
.
.
.

function _displayAbc($tpl)
{
   global $mainframe;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a ideas is you can using iframe:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.modal', 'a.modal');
<a class="modal" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 500, y: 400}}" href="index.php?option=com_test&view=test&tmpl=component&layout=abc">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a URL as the parameter for require. That functions expects a path, not a URL.

Instead, you should do this:

```
<?php 
  require(JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_test'.DS.
          'views'.DS.'test'.DS.'tmpl'.DS.'abc.php'); 
?>
```